# VueJS - How to use flatpickr to only choose month and day, but not year

Tags: javascript, vue.js, flatpickr

I want to create a flat picker in my Vue project, so that the users only input their birth month and birth day, but not birth year. Reason behind this is a lot of the customers refuse to provide their full birth date, but is more willing to provide only the month and day.

I know how to create a date picker on my Vue project, as such:

```
*CustomerModal.vue*
<template>
  ...
  
          <flat-picker
            :config="dpconfig"
            class="form-control datepicker"
            v-model="end_date"
            :placeholder="$t('End Date')"
            ref="End Date"
            name="end_date"
          >
          </flat-picker>

...
</template>

import flatPicker from "vue-flatpickr-component";

export default {
  components: {
    flatPicker,
  },
  data: {
    dpconfig: {
      wrap: true,
      altInput: true,
      dateFormat: "Y-m-d",
      altFormat: "Y-m-d",
      ariaDateFormat: "Y-m-d",
    },
  },
```

The above code will create a date picker. It has year, month and day. However, what can I do if I want to only ask the users for month and day?

Thank You!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing date format to `"m-d"` should do the job.

```
 export default {
  components: {
    flatPicker,
  },
  data: {
    dpconfig: {
      wrap: true,
      altInput: true,
      dateFormat: "m-d",
      altFormat: "m-d",
      ariaDateFormat: "m-d",
      onOpen : function(event){
      let instances = document.getElementsByClassName("flatpickr-month");
      for(let i= 0; i< instances.length; i+=1)
        {
          instances[i].style.display="none";
        }
    }
    },
  },
}
```

Comment: Thank you sazzad for your suggetion! Now, when the user clicks on the flat picker box, a calendar drops down with year, month and day selection. After the user chooses a selected date, the output is MM-DD instead of YYYY-MM-DD. However, I want it so that when the user clicks on the flat picker box, the calendar will not have the year option, but just month and day.

Comment: Unfortunately there is no such option in the config to hide the year selection. you can use the `onOpen` event handler to hide the year selection element which have a class `flatpickr-month` using style property.

Comment: Thank you again, sazzad! I am not sure if what your method corresponds to [this](https://github.com/flatpickr/flatpickr/issues/216) . I just couldnt figure out how to use css to filter out the year option. Any suggestions are appreciated!

Comment: @FrederickW i have updated the answer. Please have a look now.

Comment: this works by hiding the year and the month. What if I only want to hide the year? Is there a class called flatpickr-year ? Or something similar. Thanks for your input, Sazzad!

Comment: in the version i checked, the year selection is wrapped in the div having class `numInputWrapper` . You can use this class name instead of `flatpickr-month` if you want to hide only the year selection

Comment: BINGO! This is exactly what I am looking for. Thank you so much! By the way, how did you know that the div is called numInputWrapper? How can I find out this kind of information by myself next time?

Comment: You can inspect that element and see all the available info there like this https://prnt.sc/26ez5z2 .

Comment: how about year only .. not month and day,

Answer (score 0):

To use Flatpickr in Vue.js and configure it to only allow selection of the month and day (without the year), you can follow the example below. Note that you need to use the monthSelect plugin for Flatpickr and set the noCalendar option to true. Also, make sure to include the necessary styles for the monthSelect plugin.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import monthSelectPlugin from "flatpickr/dist/plugins/monthSelect";
import "flatpickr/dist/flatpickr.min.css";
import "flatpickr/dist/plugins/monthSelect/style.css";



import Flatpickr from "react-flatpickr";
function App() {
  const [date, setDate] = useState(new Date());
  const onCloseHandle = (date) => {
    setDate(date[0]);
  };
  return (

    <div className="App">
      <span>Selected Date : {JSON.stringify(date)}</span>
      <br />
      <Flatpickr
        options={{
          plugins: [
            new monthSelectPlugin({
              shorthand: true,
              dateFormat: "m/Y",
              altInput: true,
              altFormat: "m/Y",
              theme: "light"
            })
          ],
          static: true
        }}
        value={date}
        onClose={onCloseHandle}
      />
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

In this example:

1 We import the necessary Flatpickr components and styles.

2 We define the selectedDate data property to store the selected date.

3 We configure the Flatpickr component with the flatpickrConfig

4 object, which includes the monthSelect plugin and other options.
The noCalendar option is set to true to disable the calendar,
allowing only the selection of the month and day.

5 The v-model directive is used to bind the selected date to the
selectedDate property.
https://codesandbox.io/s/flatpickr-react-kcp2mq

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).